# value to string is set to null irrespective of the condition in c#

Tags: c#

I am assigning a value to var in c#

```
string fileName  = properties.AfterProperties["Name"] != null ? properties.AfterProperties["Name"].toString(): "";
```

Now the problem i face is fileName is null irrespective of the value of `properties.AfterProperties["Name"]`

I checked value of `properties.AfterProperties["Name"]` which had fileName and i also checked the entire assignment statement in the immediate window and it assigning the value of `properties.AfterProperties["Name"]` to the `fileName`

But when i press f11 after that assignment line, the value of `fileName` is null!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this as well

```
string fileName  = properties.AfterProperties["Name"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(properties.AfterProperties["Name"].toString()) ? properties.AfterProperties["Name"].toString(): "";
```

By the way small hint:

```
properties.AfterProperties["Name"] != null // This check avoids object reference errors.

!String.IsNullOrEmpty(properties.AfterProperties["Name"].toString()) // This check will avoid your problem - returning empty instead of null.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of `AfterProperties`.

In the first condition you used `properties.AfterProperties["Name"]`, but in the assignment you used `properties.AfterProperties["Name"].ToString()`

Maybe `properties.AfterProperties["Name"]` is not null but `properties.AfterProperties["Name"].ToString()` returns null.

Comment: i also tried removing the .toString() :( but didnt work

Comment: what is the type of AfterProperties?

Answer (score 1):

May be trying like this:

`string fileName  = !properties.AfterProperties["Name"].Equals(null) ? properties.AfterProperties["Name"].toString(): "";`